# Changing overlay color for single item in a grid with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```html
<div id="56c46f8385953" class="mg_box mg_pre_show col1_3 row1_3 m_col1_2 m_row1_3 mgi_14 mg_pag_1 mg_gallery mg_transitions mg_closed   " rel="pid_14"  mgi_w="0.333" mgi_h="0.333" mgi_mw="0.5" mgi_mh="0.333" >
  <div class="mg_shadow_div">
    <div class="img_wrap mg_has_txt_under" >
      <div>
        <img src="" class="thumb" alt="NYC" fullurl="//testseite24-7.de/wp-content/uploads/ewpt_cache/367x367_85_1_c_FFFFFF_40d34172585f94f3753e12e0e4b051fc.jpg" mobileurl="//testseite24-7.de/wp-content/uploads/ewpt_cache/400x267_85_1_c_FFFFFF_40d34172585f94f3753e12e0e4b051fc.jpg" />
        <noscript>
          <img src="//testseite24-7.de/wp-content/uploads/ewpt_cache/367x367_85_1_c_FFFFFF_40d34172585f94f3753e12e0e4b051fc.jpg" alt="NYC" />
        </noscript>
        <div class="overlays">
          <div class="mgom_layer mgom_full_img_layer mgom_18_0 ">
          </div
            ><div class="mgom_txt_wrap mgom_18_3 ">
          <div class="mgom_layer mgom_descr mgom_18_1">
          </div>
          <div class="mgom_layer mgom_txt_block mgom_18_2">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="http://testseite24-7.de/#!mg_ld_14" class="mg_seo_dl_link">'</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dear community members,

I am not that experienced in coding and I need your help.

I have a portfolio on my site (I am using for this *Media Grid – WordPress responsive portfolio* and *Media Grid Overlay manager add-on*). Overlay Manager add-on allows only one overlay-design for the whole single grid (the only manageable feature for each single item is excerpt). I would like to set different overlay colors for the items in one grid (for instance NYC). The developer says it is possible but he does not make such customization (in particular he wrote “*However is already feasible, but you need to know CSS and how to inspect code. Each grid item has got an unique selector based on its ID, then isn't particularly difficult to achieve it*”). I can define these IDs (for exsample **#56c46f838595** for NYC Gallery) and selector (class) for the overlay - in my case the layer with the changing backgound color has a class **.mgom_18_0**. I have been trying to change a color for one item, but did not succeed in it. All details I add below.

I would appreciate any help in this issue! I thank you in advance!

Best regards, Mike

UPDATE. I added an HTML part. Now I am a bit confused because the ID is changing every time I load the page one more time...

the site where I test the settings http://testseite24-7.de/

CSS part for the overlay type I am using for my test-city-grid.
And here is ELEMENT LEGEND for Plugin.[Legend Classes Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE8fG.jpg)

```
/* ***** 18 - test OVERLAY ***** */ 

    .mgom_18_0 { /* full_img_layer */
            top: 0px; left: 0px;
                background-color: #ffffff;opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);                 
                transition: all 0ms ease 0s;
                -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease 0s; /* older webkit */
                -ms-transition: all 0ms ease 0s;                    
        z-index: 890; 
    }

    .mg_box:hover .mgom_18_0 {
            top: 0px; left: 0px;
                background-color: #ffb514;opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80);
                        }

    .mgom_18_1 { /* descr */
            text-align: left;
                font-size: 14px;                    
                color: #222222;line-height: 19px;                   
    }

    .mg_box:hover .mgom_18_1 {              
                color: #383838;
    }

    .mgom_18_2 { /* txt_block */
            top: 0px; left: 0px;
                background-color: #ffffff;opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);                 
                transition: all 0ms ease 0s;
                -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease 0s; /* older webkit */
                -ms-transition: all 0ms ease 0s;                    
    }

    .mg_box:hover .mgom_18_2 {
            top: 0px; left: 0px;
                background-color: #ffffff;opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);                 
    }

        .mg_box .mgom_18_3.mgom_txt_wrap > *:not(.mgom_txt_block) {
            opacity: 0;
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);   
        }

        .mg_box:hover .mgom_18_3.mgom_txt_wrap > *:not(.mgom_txt_block) {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
        }
        .mgom_18_3.mgom_txt_wrap > * {
            transition:         opacity 0ms ease 0s;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0ms ease 0s;
            -ms-transition:     opacity 0ms ease 0s;
        }

.mgom_18_3.mgom_txt_wrap {
    top: 0px; left: 0px;            
                transition: all 0ms ease 0s;
                -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease 0s; /* older webkit */
                -ms-transition: all 0ms ease 0s;            

}

.mg_box:hover .mgom_18_3.mgom_txt_wrap {
    top: 0px; left: 0px;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a Html part so everyone could see it even if the site is not there anymore. I hope that's what yout have meant!

Answer (score 0):

Find a line of code in your html

```
<div class="mgom_layer mgom_full_img_layer mgom_18_0">
```

And change it to:

```
<div class="mgom_layer mgom_full_img_layer mgom_18_0" style="background-color: red">
```

Then refresh the page. You will see the difference. The best idea is to use id, but it also will help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunatelly I am working in Wordpress and cannot edit HTML so I will have to do it with CSS.